# Apps. that provides opamp output mathematical functions, and applications that provide opamp topology according to the output function

Tags: operational-amplifier

There is a very nice application that gives mathematical output of opamp circuits: Maplesim,
Create the existing opamp circuit and see the mathematical expression at the output. (Please let me know if there are similar applications)

[image]
Are there any applications where we can create a certain function equation for the output and transform it into a circuit topology with opamps?